# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, magento2.3.0, php-7.1

I have installed **`Smile_Elasticsearch`** extension.It is working fine with the default mode but when I enabled developer mode it is showing an error.

> **Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object in
>   app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php
>   on line 150**

Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

Technology Detail's:

- Magento version: 2.3
- Smile Elasticsearch version: 2.7.0 (which is compatible with Magento 2.3)
- Installed Elasticsearch version: 5.6.15 (which is compatible with magento 2.3)
- PHP version: 7.1

So, Please let me know how can I fix this error?
Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.!!!

Comment: Please apply below patch for the same - https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite/issues/1085

Comment: select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code="virtual_rule";

Answer (score 1):

The error you are seeing in the file app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php suggests that there is an issue with a callback function that is being called in the file. This error is typically caused when the callback function is not a valid class or object.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following:

1. Check that the file
   app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php
   exists and that it is not corrupted. If necessary, you can try
   downloading the extension again and reinstalling it.
2. Check that the class
   Smile\ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory\Model\Layer\Filter\Category exists
   and that it is being loaded properly. You can do this by adding the
   following code at the beginning of the file
   app/code/Smile/ElasticsuiteVirtualCategory/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

   **die('Class: ' . get_class($this));**

If the class is not being loaded properly, you may need to check your Magento configuration or contact the extension developer for further assistance.

Answer (score -1):

Here parameter 1 `[$virtualRule, $callback]` must be an array to callback these functions.

Here is the solution.

Goto line around `151` to `156` `/module-elasticsuite-virtual-category/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php`

```php
if ($data === false) {
    $virtualRule = $category->getVirtualRule();
    //$data = call_user_func_array([$virtualRule, $callback], [$category]);
    $cacheData = serialize($data);
    $this->cache->save($cacheData, $cacheKey, [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::CACHE_TAG]);
}
```

Change to this:

```php
if ($data === false) {
    $virtualRule = $category->getVirtualRule();
    $data = call_user_func_array(array[$virtualRule, $callback], [$category]);
    $cacheData = serialize($data);
    $this->cache->save($cacheData, $cacheKey, [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::CACHE_TAG]);
}
```

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: You just changed the array form from the new `[]` to the old `array()` version, so in fact nothing will change